# LUA: проблема получения данных из стека - функция lua_getstack(...) всегда возвращает 0

Tags: delphi, lua, delphi-10-seattle

Есть код программы

```
function GetStatck():TList<TCallStack>;
var
  Level     : integer;
  ar        : Plua_Debug;
  CallStack : TCallStack;
begin
  .....
  Result := TList<TCallStack>.Create;   
  .....
  Level := 1;
  ....
  // Почему при попытке заполнить запись ar данными из стека, постоянно получаем 0 ?
  while lua_getstack(L, Level, @ar) = 1 do
    begin
      ....
      // СЮДА НЕ ПОПАДАЕМ
      ....
      CallStack := TCallStack.Create; 
      ....
      Result.Add(CallStack); 
      ....
    end;
  ....
end;
```

и код основной программы, например:

....

```
procedure TFormMain.DoLua();
var
  ListCallStack: TList<TCallStack>;
begin

  Lua.DoString('print "Hello World"');
  ....
  // Тут хотелось бы увидеть результат, получить список данных
  ListCallStack := GetStatck(); 
  ....

end;
```

Как получить Traceback используя функцию **lua_getstack** ?

**Вот простой пример средствами LUA получить TraceBack - для HelloWorld**

```
procedure TFormMain.DoLua();
 .....
Lua.DoString(
     'print "Hello World"' + #13#10 +
     'print (debug.traceback());'
```

**Результат:**

> hello stack traceback:   [string "print "Hello World" ..."]:2: in main
>   chunk

Помогите решить задачу, в чем проблема? почему допустим как пример выполняя такой код, данные стека тоже видны...:

```
function low ()
        mid()
        end

function mid()
        high(5)
        end

function high(val)
        print (debug.traceback())
        end

print ("Started")
low()
print ("Completed")
```

Использую Delphi 10 и обвертку для LUA (VerySimple) - http://blog.spreendigital.de/2015/02/18/verysimple-lua-2-0-a-cross-platform-lua-5-3-0-wrapper-for-delphi-xe5-xe7/

Comment: А что вы хотите увидеть в стеке, выполняя `print "Hello World"`?  Стек, в общем случае, хранит локальные переменные функций, адреса возврата из них же и то что вы туда сами поместили. Что из этого присутствует в вашей первой программе? Во второй понятно, на момент вызова `debug.traceback()` там будут три адреса возврата.

Comment: Hello World  написал как пример, можно без вопросов выполнить код LUA примера ниже.... хотелось бы получить debug.traceback...используя  функцию  lua_getstack(L, Level, @ar)

Comment: А если сделать `Level := 0;`?

Comment: пробовал, то же самое lua_getstack(L, Level, @ar) возвращает 0.... уже мозг кипит....

Comment: Может нужно предварительно сделать `ar := AllocMem(SizeOf(Tlua_Debug));`?

Comment: сделал так `ar := AllocMem(SizeOf(lua_Debug));` - тот же результат.... ни чего не получаеться

Comment: А может там в стеке и нет ничего?

Comment: я показывал пример с HelloWorld что в стеке лежит фраза `hello stack traceback: [string "print "Hello World" ..."]:2: in main chunk` , если сразу выполнить команду `'print (debug.traceback());'`

Comment: В описании `lua_getstack` сказано: «получает информацию о стеке времени выполнения», т.е., как я понял, она предназначена для вызова в хуках. Вы же пытаетесь её вызвать после завершения программы, а это уже не runtime.

Comment: @Alekcvp Вы правы! Я то же начитался доков и думаю что надо делать ХУКи и там уже считывать значения get_stack, как только у меня получиться реализовать этот вариант, я сам напишу ответ, как правильно получать данные.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо всем кто помогал в комментариях! Особенно коллеге [Alekcvp](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/206219/alekcvp), который прямо в комментариях указал, на ошибку в указанной мной реализацию. Вся проблема заключается в том, что необходимо функцию **function GetStatck():TList;**, вызывать в реализованных хуках для получения стека, допустим сделать так:

```
procedure LuaHook(L: lua_State; ar: Plua_Debug); cdecl;
var
  ListCallStack : TList<TCallStack>
begin
  // делаем проверку на BREAKPOINT... 
  // если они удовлетворяют нашему условию то получаем стэк
  ... 
  ListCallStack := GetStatck();
  ...
end;
```

все это сделать надо перед выполнением скрипта, командой:

```
...
lua_sethook(L, LuaHook, LUA_MASKLINE, 0);
luaL_dostring(L,НАШ_СКРИПТ);
...
```